# Bootstrap Modals Grab Data

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I am creating a site using bootstrap, and wanted to use modals. What I am trying to do is make my code and efficient as possible. What I want to do is have a button/link similar to this

```
<a href="modals/faq.php" class="modal">faq</a>
```

When someone clicks this link it opens a modal (still on the index.php page) and grabs all the data from faq.php and displays it...

here is the code I have for a modal...

```
<button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#cashout" data-loading-text="Loading..." class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block"><i class="icon-btc"></i> Cash Out</button>
<center>
    <div class="modal fade" id="cashout" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                     <h4 class="modal-title">Head goes here</h4>

                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">body goes here</div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</center>
```

Basically whenever I have the class set as modal, it grabs data from a link and pastes it above. I hope you understand what I mean by this. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way of doing this, that I can think of at least would be to use Ajax to grab the return data of your php page. Once you have the data you can use jQuery to append it to the elements of your choice.

```
$.ajax({
url: "faq.php",
type: "POST",
async: false,
data:  {"search": str},
success: function(data){
        alert("test");
        $("#result").html(data);
    }
});
```

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for or not.